# Upgrade React-Bootstrap from 0.31.0 to 0.32.4 ( UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY )

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im trying to upgrade my `react-bootstrap` version from 0.31.0 to 0.32.4.

Im getting a `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.0`

But looking at my `package.json` i do have `react": "^15.4.0!` in the file.

What could the reason be then?

Below is my package.json file content.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "transport": "watchify js/app.js -v -t babelify -p livereactload -o public/js/bundle.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "browserify": "^14.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "fakerator": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-less": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-zip": "^4.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "livereactload": "^3.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react-proxy": "^1.1.8",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.0",
    "fixed-data-table-2": "^0.7.17",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "ramda": "^0.23.0",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.22",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-google-charts": "^1.5.5",
    "react-redux": "^4.3.0",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.8",
    "react-widgets": "^3.4.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^6.8.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is the full message in command:

```
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to E:\MelaSolutions\WEB\Chronic\node_modules\react-widgets\node_modules\dom-helpers
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to E:\MelaSolutions\WEB\Chronic\node_modules\react-widgets\node_modules\warning
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to E:\MelaSolutions\WEB\Chronic\node_modules\react-widgets\node_modules
E:\MelaSolutions\WEB\Chronic
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.0
`-- react-bootstrap@0.32.4
  +-- @babel/runtime-corejs2@7.5.5
  | +-- core-js@2.6.9
  | `-- regenerator-runtime@0.13.3
  +-- dom-helpers@3.4.0
  | `-- @babel/runtime@7.5.5
  |   `-- regenerator-runtime@0.13.3
  +-- invariant@2.2.4
  +-- keycode@2.2.0
  +-- prop-types@15.7.2
  | `-- loose-envify@1.4.0
  +-- prop-types-extra@1.1.0
  | `-- react-is@16.9.0
  +-- react-overlays@0.8.3
  +-- react-transition-group@2.9.0
  | +-- loose-envify@1.4.0
  | +-- prop-types@15.7.2
  | `-- react-lifecycles-compat@3.0.4
  `-- uncontrollable@5.1.0

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
> (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9:
> wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN react-redux@4.3.0 requires a
> peer of react@^0.14.0 but none was installed. npm ERR! Windows_NT
> 10.0.18362 npm ERR! argv "H:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "H:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
> "install" "--save" "react-bootstrap@0.32.4" npm ERR! node v6.11.0 npm
> ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! path
> E:\MelaSolutions\WEB\Chronic\node_modules\react-widgets\node_modules\dom-helpers
> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall access
> 
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access
> 'E:\MelaSolutions\WEB\Chronic\node_modules\react-widgets\node_modules\dom-helpers'
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access
> 'E:\MelaSolutions\WEB\Chronic\node_modules\react-widgets\node_modules\dom-helpers'
> npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm
> ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
> ERR! enoent
> 
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     E:\MelaSolutions\WEB\Chronic\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Might seem funny, but did you try removing `node_modules` folder and lock files, then re-installing modules with yarn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem you are facing is because of not having `write` permission on the `node_modules`, and NOT about the version of `react` as a peer dependency.

In order to fix this issue there are several solutions:

**General Solution(working in all operating systems):**

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder
2. Reinstall the dependencies (`npm install`, or preferably `yarn`)

If for any reason you still have problems (it is worth deleting `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` and then reinstalling packages

**UNIX:**
run this in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R someuser:somegroup /path/to/your/project/node_modules
```